# Adding Analytics API permission to a Google Sign-In authorization

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-signin

I have a web app that uses the usual `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly` scope on an OAuth button, and it's working fine. However, I would also like the ability for users to sign in via Google so they don't have to make a new login and password just for my app. When I implement that, I'd like to not require them to hit Login with Google, followed by another Authorize this App button - not the best user experience right out of the gate.

Is it possible to add the Google Analytics permission scope to a Google Sign-In button? If it matters, it's a Flask app with most of the stuff happening on front-end Javascript at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to spend more time in docs. You can easily accomplish this by adding your scope to the `scope:` list from Google's example:

```
var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
    });
};
```

The relevant doc page: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button